# Torus Generated by Polygon

Tags: geometry

Is there any special name or qualifier for a torus generated by a polygon (say a rectangle or trapezoid) revolved around the external axis in the same plane?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is a [Toroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toroid)